# Getting unexpected (by me) extra characters using dput() to create a txt file

Tags: r

**Note:**  *I expect this is likely a duplicate question.  However, when I searched for an answer, I failed to find one, so thanks for your patience.*

**Issue:**  When I use `dput()` to write certain lines of an existing `.txt` file to a new `.txt` file, I'm seeing extra, unexpected characters, e.g., `c(\`.

**Repro steps:**

1. Download a `zip` file containing the `.txt` to read from:

   ```
   download.file(url = "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/dsscapstone/dataset/Coursera-SwiftKey.zip", "dataset.zip")
   ```
2. Unzip the file:

   ```
   unzip(zipfile = "dataset.zip")
   ```
3. Read in a couple lines to preview the data:

   ```
   readLines("final/en_US/en_US.blogs.txt",n=2)
   [1] "In the years thereafter, most of the Oil fields and platforms were named after pagan â€œgodsâ€."
   [2] "We love you Mr. Brown."
   # Ignore the characters around "gods" for this discussion
   ```
4. Write the lines to a new file using `dput()`:

   ```
   dput(readLines("final/en_US/en_US.blogs.txt",n=2),"dputtest.txt")
   ```
5. Read in the the lines from `dputtest.txt` and see the new characters:

   ```
   readLines("dputtest.txt")
   [1] "c(\"In the years thereafter, most of the Oil fields and platforms were named after pagan â€œgodsâ€.\", "
   [2] "\"We love you Mr. Brown.\")"
   ```

**Possible causes:**  I wonder if this has something to do with the file encoding or maybe a necessary `sep =` argument's missing.

Please let me know if you need anything else from me to understand the issue or to reproduce it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dput` outputs a *parseable* representation of an object, such that you can feed it back to the R command line and obtain the original object. For example:

```
dput(letters, "test.txt")
let <- eval(parse("test.txt"))
identical(let, letters)  # TRUE
```

What you probably want is `writeLines`, `write.table`, or `write` depending on your data.

Comment: Thanks!  On a somewhat related side note, I tried to tag this post with `dput()` or, alternatively, `dput` and both were unavailable.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using `writeLines()` rather than `dput()`:

```
rr <- readLines("final/en_US/en_US.blogs.txt",n=2)
writeLines(rr,"output.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use dput to save data then use dget to read data back to R.

```
txt <- c("First line", "Second line")
f <- tempfile()
dput(txt, f)
txt2 <- dget(f)
identical(txt, txt2)
```